Pass collection variable from LWC back to Flow
I have my own LWC component in my flow. The LWC component returns an array at the end with several entries of the type "Requested_Spare_Part__c". I have also configured the meta.xml as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <apiVersion>59.0</apiVersion>

    <isExposed>true</isExposed>

    <targets>

        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>

    </targets>

    <targetConfigs>

        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">

            <property name="outputVariable" type="@salesforce/schema/Requested_Spare_Part__c[]"

                role="outputOnly"

                label="Output Variable array"

                description="The output variable that will be used to pass data to the flow." />

        </targetConfig>

    </targetConfigs>

</LightningComponentBundle>

This is my javascript methode to get the data.
import { api, LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import searchProducts from '@salesforce/apex/RequestedSparePartController.searchProducts';

export default class MultiRequestedSparePartInput extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    @api
    get outputVariable() {
        let result = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            let row = this.data[i];
            result.push({
                Spare_Part__c: row.spare_part__c,
                Quantity__c: row.quantity__c                
            });
        }
        console.log('result');
        console.log(result);
        return result;       
    }
}

So far everything compiles correctly, but the output in the flow does not meet the expectations. In the browser console, the output looks like this:
[

    {

        "Spare_Part__c": "01t5p00000COqi9AAD",

        "Quantity__c": 1

    },

    {

        "Spare_Part__c": "01t5p00000COqnAAAT",

        "Quantity__c": 1

    }

]

But in the flow like this:
Lightning Component: testcomp

Screen component: c:createRequestedSparePart

Inputs:

Outputs:

outputVariable = requestedSpareParts2BCreated ([[Requested_Spare_Part__c (Spare_Part__c:01t5p00000COqi9AAD, Quantity__c:1)], [Requested_Spare_Part__c (Spare_Part__c:01t5p00000COqnAAAT, Quantity__c:1)]])

So I cannot iterate over the list and enrich it with further data. Because the list outputs null when iterating. This does not correspond to the definition of the variable:
Data Type: Record
Object: Requested Spare Part
Allow multiple values (collection) = true
What am I doing wrong? Where is the error?
The variable is defined like that:

After receiving this collection it is possible to iterate that list, but it is not of the type I defined. It is null:

here is a screenshot of my iteration as well:


update to show creation
This is a simple proof of concept using the same metadata markup and I was able to pass back a list of custom object records (payment__c) records from LWC to flow and then update the records in a loop, and create then for the parent Opportunity
    import {api, LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
export default class DemoFlow extends LightningElement {
    @api outputVariable;
    data = [];
    handleSetOutput() {
        this.data.push({OptyId: '006aj000003SHx3AAG', Amount: 100});
        this.data.push({OptyId: '006aj000003SHx3AAG', Amount: 200});
    }
    @api
    get outputVariable2() {
        let result = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
            let row = this.data[i];
            result.push({
                Opportunity__c: row.OptyId,
                Amount__c: row.Amount
            });
        }
        return result;
    }
}

 <!-- Demo Flow -->
<template>
<lightning-button onclick={handleSetOutput} label="Set Output"></lightning-button>
</template>





I added a part of my javascript.
I think the main difference to your suggestion is that the record does not yet exist. In your code you get it from the database via the Apex method, but I don't understand why it's different in my variant. I have an array and there are objects in the array.
Do you manage to construct an account in your code and then execute "create Record" in the flow?

Changed the flow to create records for a custom object that is a child of Opportunity. I was able to get them back and update a field on each record in a loop and then create them

How is the requestedSpareParts2BCreated  being defined?

Thank you. Your output look like mine. How can you iterate that. I get null pointer when I am iterating. I added some more screenshots to my previous post.

The only other place I can think of is where you call the LWC - are you correctly assigning the output variable from the LWC to requestedSpareParts2BCreated ?
